# Finding a specific element in an NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller

I've got an NSArrayController that contains a few elements. These elements has got a few attributes like 'name', 'interformation' etc.

What i want is simply to find an element in the NSArrayController which has the name attribute set to, lets say, 'Mads'.

Since efficiency isn't an great issue here i would just do a linear search by iterating over all the elements in the NSArrayController while checking if the 'name' attribute is 'Mads'.

But I can't seem to get an NSIterator from the NSArrayController, so I'm wondering if there's another way to do this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using the content?

ie

```
// ac is an NSArrayController*
for (MyObject *mob in ac.content) {
    if ([mob.name isEqualToString:@"something"]) {
        // found
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Get the `arrangedObjects`, which is an array, and either iterate on that or use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

That's assuming that it wouldn't be more appropriate to set the `filterPredicate` of the array controller. If you do go that way, then `arrangedObjects` will contain only the matching objects.

Comment: Can't accept two answers to one question apparently :/ but this answer is equally.